# Query where there are only two rows with specific data

Tags: mysql

I have a table with `room` which has a data of who are in it. Each room has have 0 to any number of people and each person can be in multiple rooms simultaneously. (simplified below)

```
id      name

1       John
1       Peter
1       Jill
2       John    <--- room # I want
2       Jill    <--- room # I want
3       Someoneelse
...
```

If I want to look for a room where there is John and Jill and no one else, what would be an elegant & efficient way to select the room number?

Something like this works...

```
SELECT r1.id 
FROM  `room` r1,  `room` r2
WHERE 
    r1.name != r2.name
    AND r1.id = r2.id
    AND r1.name = 'John'
    AND r2.name = 'Jill'
    AND r1.id
    IN (
        SELECT id
        FROM user_conversation
        GROUP BY id
        HAVING COUNT( * ) = 2
    )
```

But I feel like there would be a much more efficient & elegant way to get this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need self-joining or subqueries at all. This query does the trick:

```
select
id
from
your_table t
group by id
having sum(name = 'John') + sum(name = 'Jill') = 2 and count(*) = 2;
```

- see it working live in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/08bde/2/0)

`name = 'whatever'` in the `sum()` function returns 1 or 0, true or false.

Comment: This is not just a query, but a work of art. +1 for a single pass aggregation. Very slick !!!